# Why is pysnmp sending a snmp trap as TCP and changing the port?

Tags: python, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I'm sending a trap using pysnmp, but somehow the trap is getting there via TCP instead of UDP, and it is also changing the port, which I told it to use 162, but it's sending as 4222.

This is the code:

```
next(sendNotification(SnmpEngine(),
     CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
     UdpTransportTarget(('ipv4', 162)),
     ContextData(),
     'trap',
     
     [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0'), OctetString('TEST TEST TEST'))]))
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can only assume something on the wire captured this trap message over UDP and sent a TCP message instead. You need to troubleshoot over the wire, as the code can only take you this far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the IP address is not correct  for *UdpTransportTarget()*

or

try giving *transportAddr=('127.0.0.1', 162)*

```
 UdpTransportTarget(transportAddr=('127.0.0.1', 162)),
```

Comment: I changed to "ipv4" just to hide the ip

Comment: If thats the case, can you try other snmp python libraries to send the trap. or use wireshark and check the packet if its sending in TCP or UDP.

Comment: More like a comment than answer.